# Azure DevOps: Wiki page with WikiHttpClient not found

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I created a project wiki in `Azure DevOps` and want to get the wiki markdown pages in my .NET application. When using the link

https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/wiki/wikis/KIS.wiki/pages/News

The markdown gets shown in the browser. When I try to do that in code, I am getting

> "Wiki page ‘/News/_apis/connectionData’ could not be found. Ensure that the path of the page is correct and the page exists."

My code looks like this:

```
var url = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/wiki/wikis/KIS.wiki/pages/News");
var personalAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var credentials = new VssCredentials(new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken));

using (var connection = new VssConnection(url, credentials))
{
    var wikiClient = connection.GetClient<WikiHttpClient>();
    var markdown = wikiClient.GetWikiAsync("KIS.wiki").Result;
}
```

The error appears on GetClient().

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple problems with how you're trying to get the page content.

1. The url given to the connection should be the "project base path" 
   `private static string BasePath = $"https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}";`
2. You're using the `GetWikiAsync(...)` method when you want to be using the `GetPageAsync(...)` method

### Here's an example

```cs
private readonly IVssCredentialsFactory _credentialsFactory;

private const string ApiVersion = "5.1";
private static string BasePath = $"https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}";
private const string Organization = "company";
private const string Project = "project";

public AzureRepository(IVssCredentialsFactory credentialsFactory)
{
    _credentialsFactory = credentialsFactory;
}

public void GetWikiPage()
{
    using (var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(BasePath), _credentialsFactory.GetCredentials()))
    {
        var wikiClient = connection.GetClient<WikiHttpClient>();
        var wikiId = "KIS.wiki";
        var path = "/News";
        var page = wikiClient.GetPageAsync(Project, wikiId, path, includeContent : true).Result;
        var content = page.Page.Content;
    }
}
```

*notes about this sample:*

- *`IVssCredentialsFactory` is my creation, so don't look for it in the lib*
- *The injection of the factory is were the PAT or oAuth token is, so don't think you're doing anything wrong there. You're not.*
- *I hope it's obvious that the method isn't doing anything with the result, b/c let's face it, it's a sample.*

### If you're not already

You should look at the [c# client samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/master/ClientLibrary/Samples). It's not exhaustive, but can be helpful.

Comment: I didn't see what the base url  is - thank you very much!